# MVC Generar excel por medio de un store procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando un reporte en MVC con un procedimiento almacenado que tiene como entradas 3 entras uno es el mes, ano,tipo de cambio.y en mi pagina tiene 3 input entradas para que ingrese y cuando presione exportar se baje un archivo excel ,pero no logro crear llamado de al excel

Basicamente requiero ingresar los parametros al darle click generar el excel.

```html
 public ActionResult Reporte(int mes,int ano,decimal tipo)
        {
            var db = new Covi001Entities();
            SqlParameter parametro1 = new SqlParameter("@mes", mes);
            SqlParameter parametro2 = new SqlParameter("@ano", ano);
            SqlParameter parametro3 = new SqlParameter("@tipo", tipo);

            var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<ReporteExcelaudi_Result>("exec ReporteExcel @mes @ano @tipo", parametro1, parametro2, parametro3);






            return View(data);
        }
```

Mi store procedure recibe 3 parametros que los estoy enviado en el fileresult,

```html
USE [Covi001]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ReporteExcel]    Script Date: 06/11/2019 12:38:58 p.m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReporteExcel] 
@mes int , 
@ano int,
@tipo decimal

AS
BEGIN


SELECT     '31/07/2016' as FECHA, a.dpercierre,  a.dfechaform as FORMALIZACION, a.dfechavenc as VENCIMIENTO, A.dfepagreal AS FECHAPAGO, a.cnumoperac as OPERACION, b.cidasociad AS ASOCIADO, A.nmontoapro AS APROBADO, 
CASE WHEN C.CCODMONEDA = '002' THEN (A.nsaldocred * @tipo /*(SELECT ntipocamve FROM cotipocambio  WHERE (CONVERT(Char, cotipocambio.dfechatipo, 103) = '30/06/2019') AND ccodmoneda = '002')*/) ELSE A.nsaldocred END AS SALDO, 
CASE WHEN A.cfrecupago = '04' THEN 'MENSUAL' ELSE 'QUINCENAL' END AS FECUENCIAS, 
A.ntasainter AS TASA, A.CCODIGOLIN AS LINEA, CASE WHEN B.cestasocio = 'L' THEN 'LIQUIDADO' ELSE 'ACTIVO' END AS ESTATUS
/*a.npergracia, a.cnumoperac, a.cnumsolici, a.ccodifuent, f.dfesolicre, ISNULL(f.ccodigousu, '') AS ccodigous2, a.nmondespro, a.cformadese, UPPER(a.ccodigousu) AS Expr1, a.ccomentari, a.nmontoapro, a.nmontrefun, 
                         a.ntasainter, a.cidasociad, RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.cnombreaso, 1, 12)) + ' ' + RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.cnombreaso, 13, 12)) + ' ' + RTRIM(SUBSTRING(b.cnombreaso, 25, 16)) AS cnombreaso, b.dfechanaci, a.ccodigolin, c.cdetalleli, 
                         a.cstatuscre, d.cdetastatu, a.dfechaform, a.ncuotapres, a.nnumcuotas, e.ccodigoges, e.cdetagesti, a.nsaldocred, a.npagosefec, a.dfeculabon, a.dfepagreal, a.ccodigousu,
                             (SELECT        CDESCRICAT
                               FROM            ASCATEGOAS
                               WHERE        (CCODIGOCAT = a.ccodigocat)) AS ccodigocat, c.cprefijoli, a.ndesembols, a.ctipotrans, a.cnumdocume, g.ctipasient, a.cnumasient, g.cdesasien, RTRIM(ISNULL(h.cnombcorto, '')) AS cnombcorto, f.nprincsoli, 
                         i.cdetafuent, a.ccodprovee, UPPER('') AS ccodigrupo, '' AS cdescgrupo, '''' AS cdetagrupo, dbo.Fun_CalcCargCuota(a.ccodigolin, a.nmontoapro, a.nsaldocred, a.ncuotapres, a.cidasociad, a.cnumoperac) AS ncargoperi, 
                         comoneda.ccodmoneda, comoneda.cdescmoned, b.ccodsubdep, ninteredia, a.dfeproxabo, a.dfechavenc, b.ccedulasoc, z.cnombtipop, a.ccodactivi, crcodactec.cdetactivi, a.cnumfactur, a.nporcendeu, 
                         comoneda.ccodmoneda AS Expr2, comoneda.cdescmoned AS Expr3, l.cnombdivis, b.dfechainga*/
FROM            [crhprestam] AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         crcodlinea AS c ON a.ccodigolin = c.ccodigolin LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         comoneda ON c.ccodmoneda = comoneda.ccodmoneda LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         geadminusu AS j ON a.ccodigousu = j.ccodigousu LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         gesucursal ON j.ccodsucurs = gesucursal.ccodsucurs LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         crcodorgan ON a.ccodigorga = crcodorgan.ccodigorga LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         cpprovedor ON a.ccodprovee = cpprovedor.ccodprovee LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         [ashmaestra] AS b ON a.cidasociad = b.cidasociad LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         crsolicred AS f ON a.cnumsolici = f.cnumsolici LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         astipoplan AS z ON b.CTIPOPLANI = z.ctipoplani LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         crstatcred AS d ON a.cstatuscre = d.cstatuscre LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         crcodgesti AS e ON a.ccodigoges = e.ccodigoges LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         cotipasien AS g ON a.ctipasient = g.ctipasient LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         asdepartam AS k ON b.cinstdepto = k.cinstdepto LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         asdivision AS l ON b.cidivision = l.cidivision LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         asgrupinte AS m ON b.ccodgrupos = m.ccodgrupos LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         bactasbanc ON a.cctabancar = bactasbanc.cctabancar LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         bainstbanc AS h ON bactasbanc.ccodibanca = h.ccodibanca LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         crfuenrecu AS i ON a.ccodifuent = i.ccodifuent LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         crcodactec ON a.ccodactivi = crcodactec.ccodactivi LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         cotipocambio AS tc ON DATEPART(year, tc.dfechatipo) = DATEPART(year, a.dfechaform) AND DATEPART(month, tc.dfechatipo) = DATEPART(month, a.dfechaform) AND DATEPART(day, tc.dfechatipo) = DATEPART(day, a.dfechaform) 
                         AND tc.ccodmoneda = comoneda.ccodmoneda
WHERE       (month( a.dpercierre))  = @mes and (year( a.dpercierre))=@ano /*DIGITAR FECHA CIERRE CREDITOS*/ AND (YEAR(a.dpercierre) = YEAR(b.dfeccierre)) AND (MONTH(a.dpercierre) = MONTH(b.dfeccierre)) AND (DAY(a.dpercierre) = DAY(b.dfeccierre)) AND 
                         (nsaldocred BETWEEN 1.00 AND 999999999.00) AND (c.comitecart = 'N')
END
```

Este es el resultado de la variable DATA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El controlador debe ser FileResult.

```
 public FileResult Reporte(int mes, int ano, decimal tipo) {
  var db = new Covi001Entities();
  SqlParameter parametro1 = new SqlParameter("@mes", mes);
  SqlParameter parametro2 = new SqlParameter("@ano", ano);
  SqlParameter parametro3 = new SqlParameter("@tipo", tipo);

  var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<ReporteExcelaudi_Result>("exec ReporteExcel @mes @ano @tipo", parametro1, parametro2, parametro3); 
  //asumiré que la variable: "data" tiene un arreglo de bytes.     
  string fileName = "MiSuperReporteEnExcel.xslx";
  return File(data, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
 }
```

Documentación oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: Disculpa un novato en el tema , como hago para convertir data en byte?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de valor tienes en data?

Comment: Tengo el siguiente store procedure

Comment: ¿Qué devuelve ese Store Procedure?

Comment: Devuelve un listado de clientes,le envio 3 parametros .

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías editar la pregunta agregando más detalles? Un pantallazo mostrando lo que hay en `data` será de utilidad.

Comment: listo amigo puse una foto del Store procedure , la var data la estoy llenando con los datos obtenidos del SP.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100764/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-marcelo-mp).

Comment: Hola alguno me puede ayudar aun tengo problemas con la pregunta inicial